# How do i set custom path for browse server in CHEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to set a custom path for `browse server` in `CHEditer` below is my code but did not work. anyone have an idea how to resolve.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'http://demo.azureedge.net/demostorage/';
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Please refer below link to see what error I am facing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rURR4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` must point to a **folder** where `config.js` and `lang` and `plugins` folders are located. I reproduced the eroor. In my case `c` is an object and `c[a]` is `undefined` (a == "en" in my case)

Comment: Thaks for your reply, Can you please tell me exactly how do i that.

Comment: If you use local (to your server) copy of CKEditor (that is ckeditor.js, config.js and all other things are in the same folder) than you don't need `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` global variable. You can even rename ckeditor.js and change script src accordingly without setting basepath.

Comment: Thank you very much. your help is realy needful.